# Thread only has issues when it uses bluetooth function

Tags: python, multithreading, bluetooth

I want to set a thread so Bluetooth can keep scanning for devices in the background while my main program runs. 
This is what my files are structured like:

**mainprogram.py**

```
class MainClass():
    def something():
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=BluetoothClass.main, args=[self], daemon=True)
        mythread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = MainClass()
    start.something()
```

**bluetoothstuff.py**

```
class BluetoothClass():
    def main():
        devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
```

When mainprogram.py runs it gives this error:

```
WARNING: nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.
```

If I get rid of the bluetooth line in bluetoothstuff.py, and put in something else such as `print()` or `time.sleep(3)`, it runs fine without errors.

In other answers, I've seen that apparently when you use bluetooth, it "gives up" the main thread but I've tried searching and I'm still not sure what that means. I've called the thread in the file that the interpreter is running, so isn't that the main thread?

I've also tried searching for the term `nextEventMatchingMask` in Python documentation but it doesn't come up with anything so I'm not sure what this is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess but Bluetooth does not like being called in a separate thread. It causes a 'deadlock' while searching for devices. I don't understand why the thread doesn't just die because when I run Bluetooth code by itself, it ends just fine.

Anyway, I didn't really fix this but it still did what I wanted it to do. If anyone ran into the same dumb problem I did, here's what happened.

I just ran Bluetooth code like how you'd normally run imported code like this:

```
mything = BluetoothClass()
mything.main()
```

And then I ran my main program in a daemon thread.

So bluetooth runs in the main thread while main program runs in a separate thread. But it makes it look like bluetooth is running in the background and keeps running the main program until something in bluetooth is triggered.

I'm going to choose my own answer as the correct one as it did solve what I intended it to do. If someone else comes up with a better answer, I'll re-accept it as the new answer.